# Ruby の最大値と最小値を代入して、条件分岐でpしたいです。

Tags: ruby

```
A2 = 34.773381
A3 = 135.542685

A = 34.774974
B = 34.774551
C = 34.774323
D = 34.774625

A1 = 135.541896
B1 = 135.542218
C1 = 135.541641
D1 = 135.541393

＃ここででた最大値と最小値をW,X,Y,Zに代入して条件分岐をしたいです。
array1 = [A,B,C,D]
p array1.max
p array1.min

array2 = [A1,B1,C1,D1]
p array2.max
p array2.min

if (A2 > W) then
  if (A2 < X) then
    if (A2 > Y) then
      if (A2 < Z) then
        print "失敗\n"
      else
        print "成功\n"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: とりあえず、説明し難いのでarrayをarray1、array2と変えさせていただきました。W：array1のmax、X：array1のmin、Y：array2のmax、Z：array2のminとして。。。やりたい事がよくわからんです。条件パターンごとに何をしたいか記載したら良い回答が付くと思いますよ。

Comment: 質問を素直に読むと`array.max`などの結果を変数に代入するだけだと思うのですが、何に困っているのかわかりません。エラーが出ただとか、思った通りに動作しないだとか、具体的な状況を説明してください。なお、Rubyでは大文字から始まる変数名は定数として扱われるので注意してください。

Comment: 試行錯誤の段階でもなるべく意味のある変数名を付けることをお勧めします。また、A2,A3がそれぞれ何の値なのか分からない(比較の為の基準値？)、A3に至っては何処にも使われていません。

Answer (score 0):

`p array.max`という記述された部分を分解すると、`array.max`はリストの最大値を返し、`p 引数`が引数の内容を詳しく出力ですので、今回の例なら`p`で出力する代わりに変数へ代入すればいいだけのように思います。

```
array1 = [A,B,C,D]
W = array1.max
X = array1.min

array2 = [A1,B1,C1,D1]
Y = array2.max
Z = array2.min
```